# HTTPS Response after JDBC connection

Tags: java, http, jdbc

I am sending request to webserver as

```
Test1.con1.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0"); 
Test1.con1.setRequestMethod("POST");
Test1.con1.setDoInput(true); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Test1.con1.getInputStream()));
cookie  =  Test1.con1.getHeaderField(6) + ";" +  cookie;
```

JDBC code is

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://XXXXXXXX:XXXX";
Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url,"XXXXX","XXXX");
System.out.println ("Database connection established");
String myTableName = "CREATE TABLE EMPTABLE (" 
        + "idNo INT(64) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"  
        + "batch INT(64), "
        + "PRIMARY KEY(idNo))";  
try {
    statement = conn.createStatement();
    //This line has the issue
    statement.executeUpdate(myTableName);
    System.out.println("Table Created");
}
```

If I use this code before establishing JDBC connection to remote server I am getting cookies but my requirement is sending request after JDBC connection. Can anyone suggest how can i do this?

If I use code like

```
Test1.con1.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0"); 
Test1.con1.setRequestMethod("POST");
Test1.con1.setDoInput(true); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Test1.con1.getInputStream()));
cookie  =  Test1.con1.getHeaderField(6) + ";" +  cookie; /*(" I am able to get cookie)*/

String url = "jdbc:mysql://XXXXXXXX:XXXX";
Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url,"XXXXX","XXXX");
System.out.println ("Database connection established");
String myTableName = "CREATE TABLE EMPTABLE (" 
        + "idNo INT(64) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"  
        + "batch INT(64), "
        + "PRIMARY KEY(idNo))";  
try {
    statement = conn.createStatement();
    //This line has the issue
    statement.executeUpdate(myTableName);
    System.out.println("Table Created");
}
```

In this case I am able to get cookie value  But if I use code like this

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://XXXXXXXX:XXXX";
Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url,"XXXXX","XXXX");
System.out.println ("Database connection established");
String myTableName = "CREATE TABLE EMPTABLE (" 
        + "idNo INT(64) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"  
        + "batch INT(64), "
        + "PRIMARY KEY(idNo))";  
try {
    statement = conn.createStatement();
    //This line has the issue
    statement.executeUpdate(myTableName);
    System.out.println("Table Created");
}
Test1.con1.setRequestMethod("POST");
Test1.con1.setDoInput(true); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new  
InputStreamReader(Test1.con1.getInputStream()));   
cookie  =  Test1.con1.getHeaderField(6) + ";" +  cookie;
```

Here not able to get cookie

Comment: There is nothing in your code that uses JDBC. Show the actual code you are using including the JDBC code.

Comment: That still doesn't show the context of the problem. Show the code that has the problem and the code that doesn't have the problem.

Comment: Updated code    with requried data

Answer (score 0):

You data base connection code might throw an exception and it will not reach to your cookie  request code.

add try catch between db connection and print the stacktrace. So that you can identify the exact reason.

```
 try {
  String url = "jdbc:mysql://XXXXXXXX:XXXX";
  Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url,"XXXXX","XXXX");
   System.out.println ("Database connection established");
     String myTableName = "CREATE TABLE EMPTABLE (" 
    + "idNo INT(64) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"  
    + "batch INT(64), "
    + "PRIMARY KEY(idNo))";  

     statement = conn.createStatement();
    //This line has the issue
    statement.executeUpdate(myTableName);
    System.out.println("Table Created");
 }catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace()
 }
```

Comment: Nope request is sending to server and i am getting response but unable to read cookie from response. I cross checked with HTTP debugger it is showing request sent to server.